# Which one is correct: Make/Write sentences on/of your own

Tags: grammar, prepositions

Which of the following sentence is correct?

1. Make sentences on your own.
2. Make sentences of your own.
3. Write sentences on your own.
4. Write sentences of your own.

Thank you.

Comment: They are all possible. A sentence of your own is one that you have made up. _On your own_ means by yourself, without another person's help.

Comment: @Kate Bunting then what does second sentence mean? Do first and second sentences have same meaning?

Comment: Well, if you were in an English class and learning a new grammar rule, the teacher might say "Now make some sentences of your own using the rule you have just learned."

Comment: @KateBunting Thanks. I got it.